# How to get the array of pixels using TTF Format in Ruby

Tags: ruby, truetype, prawn

I tried to figure out how to do this but I didn't find any documentation of this using [TTFunk](https://github.com/prawnpdf/ttfunk) gem.

I want to do something like this (this is just an example):

```
file = TTFunk::File.open("MY_FONT.ttf")
array = file.get_array("Text", 18)
for xy in array
  draw_pixel(xy[0], xy[1], z, color)
end
```

Comment: TTFunk is a font metrics parser. It gives you font name, font family, glyph sizes, bounding boxes and the like. What you want is [font rasterization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Font_rasterization) and neither TTFunk nor Prawn do that.

Comment: The easiest way I can think to do this would be to use an image library to actually draw text into a bitmap. If you need the pixel data you can then read the bitmap back in.